# Heap Corruption Detected

Tags: c++, string, overloading, operator-keyword

The only thing that is incorrect about the output of my program, is that there is an '!' after 'fishing'. I have tried debugging it but there is never an '!' in memory.

Here is the output of this line

```
One more: gone down to the fishing! hole
```

Here is the creation of s6 and s7

```
MyString s6("gone ");
MyString s7("fishing");
```

Here is the line that produces the statement

```
cout << "One more: " << s6 + "down to the " + s7 + " hole" << endl << endl;
```

Here is the << operator overload function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
leftOp << rightOp.stringArray;

return leftOp;
}
```

Here is the + operator overload function

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const char* rightOp) const
{
    MyString result; // new object used to store result
    result.stringSize = stringSize + strlen(rightOp);
    // if the string does not fit in the array
    if( result.stringSize > result.stringCap )
    {
        delete[] result.stringArray;
        result.stringCap = ( stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;
        result.stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];
    }
    strcpy(result.stringArray, stringArray);
    strcat(result.stringArray, rightOp);
    return result;
}
```

s7 is not called anywhere else in the program so I dont think there is anymore code that needs to be shown. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should add that every other line using the + operator works correctly.

Comment: could you also show us the overloading of the << operator?

Comment: added the << overload to the original post

Comment: btw, that's probably not a "heap corruption"...

Comment: On this line `result.stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];`, what stringCap are you using for result?

Comment: @bo persson noticed that too, fixed to be result.stringCap

Comment: And that didn't change the result? :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell if the problem with your code is here.
I would look at the other members. **Have you obeyed the rule of 3**?

#### Note:

I would point out that you are breaking a fundamental OO rule.

You should not fiddle with the members of another object unless there is a `very` good reason.
Here your object is fiddling with result.

The code would be cleaner if you wrote it as:

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const char* rightOp) const
{
    MyString result(*this);   // make a copy of this.
    result += rightOp;        // Let result fiddle with its own members here.
    return result;
}
```

#### Edit:

based on comment below.

[Rule of Three](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+rule+of+three&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Basically: If your object owns dynamically allocated memory (ie it calls new/delete) then the default version of the methods generated by the compiler do not work as you want; and you should define your own versions:

Basically:

```
* Copy Constructor
* Assignment Operator
* Destructor

* Not part of rule of 3, but you probably also need a normal constructor.
```

The easy thing is the you probably already have a destructor (otherwise there would not be corruption), and the assignment operator can be written in terms of the copy constructor. So all you need to do is write a correct version of the copy constructor and everything should work.

```
/*
 * Assignment operator using Copy and swap Idiom.
 * Copy uses copy constructor (here done in pass by value)
 *
 * You then just swap the current content with the copy
 */
MyString& MyString::operator=(MyString rhs)
{
    (*this).swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Martin, the problem is clearly not about "nice oo architecture".

Comment: @Ubiquité: Correct. But writing it correctly is more likely to lead to less chance of mistakes. I am betting the problem is caused by not implementing the rule of three correctly. Without being able to see the needed methods (copy constructor/assignment operator/destructor/ (normal constructor)) it is really hard to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I am not agree, for me "writing correctly" are not a synonym of "following 00 rules"

Comment: @Ubiquité: Re-arranged so I mention what I think the problem is first (rather than second).

Answer (score 1):

If you allocat stringCap to your array, do you mind about the '\0'? The char* storing the string must be an array of size `size-of-string + 1`

The problem is probably when you concat two MyString. The second string, fishing, may have a too big stringSize value.

And instead of `result.stringCap = ( stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;` why don't simply write:

```
result.stringCap = result.stringSize + 1;
```

Comment: changing the capacity to next multiple of 16

Comment: @bluetickk: This `result.stringCap = ( stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;` does not quite work. If stringSize is (0,16,32,48) it does not change size.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate `stringArray` in the normal case, and you didn't reset the stringSize in the too-large case, and strncpy is safer:

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const char* rightOp) const
{
    MyString result; // new object used to store result
    result.stringSize = stringSize + strlen(rightOp);
    // if the string does not fit in the array
    if( result.stringSize > result.stringCap )
    {
        delete[] result.stringArray;
        result.stringCap = ( stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;
        // don't allocate here
        result.stringSize = stringCap;
    }

    // always allocate for the new string
    result.stringArray = new char[result.stringSize + 1];

    strncpy(result.stringArray, stringArray, result.stringSize);
    strncat(result.stringArray, rightOp, strlen(rightOp) + 1);
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**: Ok, disregard that.  I assumed certain things about the MyString class which are apparently not the case.  So, here's what I can point out now:

```
if( result.stringSize > result.stringCap )
{
    delete[] result.stringArray;
    result.stringCap = ( stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;
    result.stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1]; // WRONG stringCap!
    result.stringArray = new char[result.stringCap + 1]; // right stringCap
}
```

And you can try simplifying things, to narrow down the problem:

```
cout << "One more: " << s6 + "down to the " << s7 + " hole" << endl << endl;
```

maybe the issue is in `operator+(const MyString&)` instead of `operator+(const char*)`?

Comment: It seems likely to me that the default constructor of MyString allocates a some default size for `result.stringArray`. If it does not then the `delete[] result.stringArray` line would be deleting an unallocated buffer.  Assuming that is the case this code leaks memory for the common case.

Comment: the default constructor does set the default size to be 0

Comment: im assuming this is what you meant..
strncat(result.stringArray, rightOp.stringArray, strlen(rightOp.stringArray) + 1);
?

Comment: stringCap is set to 16 by the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`if( result.stringSize > result.stringCap )` should be `if( result.stringSize >= result.stringCap )` to allow for null termination.  You also need to reset `result.stringSize`.